# Read compressed files one by one

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

Suppose I have a zip containing N number of files. I want to process each file one by one using Dataflow. Is this possible?

I need to process each file in the zip and dump the data in it in a BigQuery table. So each file will be dumped in a separate BigQuery table.

I tried reading a zip file using Dataflow but it reads everything in it at once. I must be able to differentiate between the various files in the zip.

Thank You

Comment: why secuencially and not in parallel? you could have each file individually zipped and saved in cloud storage, then do the ETL

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can write one DoFn to read the catalog of files and output a tuple (Filename, Zipfile) pairs, or (offset, zipfile) pairs. Then the downstream step will receive the pairs sharded on different workers, allowing you to load separate files from the zip in parallel.

I assume there is an API to (1) list the files in the zip and (2) unzip just the specific file that you want to unzip. Hopefully this approach will work.

Comment: Okay and what if I wanted to do the same thing in parallel?

Comment: Basically my use case is that I want to read from a number of files in a folder(zipped/unzipped), process them and dump them in separate BigQuery tables. In which BigQuery table to dump a file's data is decided by the filenames. What do you recommend doing in such a scenario?

Comment: Hi @AlexAmato ... I'm sorry I forgot to tag you in the previous comments... I'm not sure if you saw it...anyways please let me know your thoughts...thank you